# Name for old-style (purple-tinged) white LEDs?

Tags: led, identification, terminology

Older white LEDs (ca. 2005-2010?) had a distinct purple tinge while modern ones have a spectrum much closer to a blackbody.  I rather like the look of the older style and would like to purchase some now.  Does anyone know what keywords to use to find the older style in a parametric search?

Comment: Sounds strange. Spectra of modern white LEDs are quite far from black body, and don't seem to have improved since 200x. There's still the large spike of blue and a dip in cyan on most white LED lamps.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These are called "Full Conversion White LEDs" though by the early two thousands they were partial conversion so you want to look for "Partial Conversion White LEDs". They worked by producing a UV light that excited a phosphorus layer that produced the white light. Some of the purple light from the UV would seep through and cause a purple tint. Also try looking up "Phosphor Film Conversion LED".

Here is an article that talks about them and their history: https://hackaday.com/2018/10/29/history-of-white-leds/

Here is a more technical article discussing it: https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/phosphor-film-conversion-for-white-leds

To be more specific the full name would be "Phosphor conversion indium gallium nitride white LED" sometimes called InGaN, the phosphor used is called yttrium aluminum garnet or YAG. Here is a picture of it:

[image]

You can buy them here (notice the blue hue in the picture):

https://www.adafruit.com/product/754?gclid=CjwKCAjwkdL6BRAREiwA-kiczD67ahIX1q9TtjzMmoOsKO2we7xG-Lax9O1Nh0yBdo2tt5wLa0cOSRoCelgQAvD_BwE

Note: The "Cool White" modern LEDs mentioned in the other answer do not have a color spectrum that looks anything like first-gen partial conversion LEDs. Cool white will still come across as white, though towards the blue part of the spectrum. But the InGaN with YAG phosphor will actually look as though it has a distinct bluish color with a strong blue peak in its color spectrum that exceeds that of modern Cool White LED.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I'm looking for.  A search for "InGaN" on Mouser brought up [these](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/239/LTW-C281DS5-1150365.pdf); the spectrum (p. 4) has a very strong peak at 465 nm (blue-violet).

Comment: @AlexHajnal Awesome,yea says in the Datasheet those are InGaN as well, that should be what your looking for. Dont forget to accept my answer please.

Comment: @AlexHajnal by the way the link I provided to buy some also show a picture and they are specifically from 2011 according to the data sheet. So I felt it was a closer match to what you were looking for.. Either should work though, but the older ones had a stronger purple hue, so you may want to go with my link.. either way, please remember to accept the answer and good luck.

Comment: This totally answers my question but I'll wait the customary 24-hours before accepting the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @AlexHajnal Sounds good, happy to help.

Comment: Could also be a normal blue one with really bad phosphor down-conversion. Early ones tended to shift to green or pink due to wide production tolerances.

Comment: All UV/Blue/Green LEDs use InGaN as their active layer, the color depends on how much Indium there is.  Blue is pretty ubiquitous for white LEDs; getting the spectrum you want is probably all about the phosphor.

Comment: @IceGlasses It isnt the InGaN by itself that produces the unique color of older LED, it is the combination of InGaN with first-gen poorly applied YAG phosphor. Other phosphors or even later gen YAG phosphors dont look the same.

Comment: I was finally able to fit the InGaN LEDs that I sourced ([LTW-420D7](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Lite-On%20PDFs/LTW-420D7.pdf)).  The spectrum appears to have more of a blackbody appearance than the ones available a few years back but still has a noticeable purple tinge.

Comment: @AlexHajnal yup thats just a matter of where it falls on the scale between partial conversion and full conversion, which itself is effected by how thick and even the phosphor layer is. so there is some variation regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the exact LEDs may not be readily available due to changes in manufacturing, modern white LEDs (and LED light fixtures) will often be called "warm white" for a more yellowy colour which mimics incandescent light or "cool white" which is more blueish like these older LEDs.  So if you choose a "cool white" LED, that will give what you're looking for.

To make this more exact, manufacturers will specify a colour temperature. [See this link](https://integral-led.com/education/warm-white-or-cool-white) for a more complete illustration of colour temperature and how it affects lighting.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. Some LEDs even come with a "color temperature" column in the datasheet, sometimes the range is as wide as 3000-27000K.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev _Not sure why this got downvoted._ Probably because the question was specifically about older white LEDs with a distinct purple tint caused from the UV spectrum used in those, and not just some LEDs with yellow tint trying to mimic warm light from classical light bulbs, essentially making this answer sort of irrelevant. Just a wild guess, though.

Comment: @NumLock The relevant part is that such LEDs (or functionally similar ones) are called "cool white" novadays.

Comment: @NumLock If you're looking for something similar to older LEDs though, then the colour temperature is *exactly* what you're looking for.  I'll add a sentence to that first paragraph if you don't think it's clear enough.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev The OP isn't looking for Cool White LEDs either, they dont look anything like early model partial conversion LEDs, which is what the OP is looking for. A cool white LED looks white, there is no blue tint. He is asking about something completely different.

the point is you simply wont find new LEDs with a color spectrum that match first gen partial conversion LEDs as the distinctive blue glow was undesirable and beyond that of Cool White.

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman LEDs with color temperature above 8000K will have blue tint, and above 25000K the tint will be blue-violet. For many purposes, this could be a reasonable choice. Don't get me wrong, I appreciate the historical perspective given in your answer, but given how subjective the looks are, this answer has its own merit.

Comment: @Graham To give you some specific numbers in terms of "Optical Power" modern Cool White LEDs Have a 0.75 relative optical power on its warm peak (the part caused by the phosophor) at 552.5 nM and its blue peak is 1.0 at 452.5. If you compare that to the InGaN w/YAG old school LEDs they have a at the same point of 552.5 also with 1.0 relative optical power, but its warm peak is at 550nM (slightly cooler) and only has a relative optical power of 0.4. 

So no a modern Cool White is not even remotely close to these older LEDs, the moderns have a 87% higher warm component from their phosphor.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev the point is a modern Cool White doesnt even come close to the color spectrum of the older InGaN w/YAG led.. Sure you can find a color spectrum that can look blueish if you push the color temperature beyond that of a typical Cool White, but even then it will have a different spectrum overall and really wont look comparable